# "Unable to find xref table" with Dompdf0.6a + FPDI

Tags: php, dompdf, fpdi

I'm trying to generate a pdf file from html using dompdf0.6a and that works fine, but then i need to encrypt it for protection, but i get error

```
FPDF error: Unable to find xref table - Maybe a Problem with 'auto_detect_line_endings'
```

However if I use older dompdf versions it works fine. I guess it generates newer pdf version that fpdi doesn't support.

btw. I traced it to FPDI/pdf_parser.php:208 (inside method pdf_read_xref())

Comment: Can you create a test PDF and upload it somewhere?

Answer (score 8):

I was able to fix this by using Adobe Acrobat Professional v8 and going to "Document -> Reduce File Size" and then choosing something really old like "Acrobat 5.0 or Later", then the error was fixed!

Answer (score 0):

The latest development version of DOMPDF might fix this problem. This is an unofficial release, however, so support is limited. See the [DOMPDF support group](http://groups.google.com/group/dompdf/msg/608cf69792d05a82) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this error right now. I'm not sure if it applies to this case, but the problem was related to the hosting.

I had exceeded the FTP quota. I changed the FTP quota to a higher value and that fixed the error.

(In Parallels Plesk Panel, FTP->FTP Manager->Quota- xxxx MB used out of xxxx in unlimited files -> Click on the button-> Enter New Disk Quota)